# Scraping un-nested html with scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using the excellent scrapy project to try and scrape the following HTML:

```
<div id="bio">
    <b>Birthplace:&nbsp;</b><a href="/tags/?id=90" target="_blank">Ireland</a>
    <br>
    <b>Location:&nbsp;</b><a href="/tags/?id=294" target="_blank">London</a>, 
    <a href="/tags/?id=64" target="_blank">UK</a>
    <br>
    <b>Ethnicity:&nbsp;</b><a href="/tags/?id=4" target="_blank">Caucasian</a><br>
</div>
```

Another example (different page):

```
<div id="bio">
    <b>Birthplace:&nbsp;</b><a href="/tags/?id=100" target="_blank">United States</a>
    <br>
    <b>Location:&nbsp;</b><a href="/tags/?id=345" target="_blank">Baltimore</a>, 
    <a href="/tags/?id=190" target="_blank">Maryland</a>,
    <a href="/tags/?id=190" target="_blank">United States</a>
    <br>
    <b>Ethnicity:&nbsp;</b><a href="/tags/?id=4" target="_blank">Black</a><br>
</div>
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
["London", "UK"]
["Baltimore", "Maryland", "United States"]
```

As you can see there are occasionally states and provinces so it's not as easy as just selecting the first 2 `<a>` tags.

Solutions I can think of:

- Detect a comma immediately after the `<a>` element. Stop when there is no comma (last element)
- Find all of the `<a>` tags between a `<b>` element and a `<br>` element
- Get a list of countries that has state/province and filter by value (I'd prefer not to do this)

**Edit:**

To clarify, the 2 examples above are from different pages. Secondly the `<b>Ethnicity</b>` element sometimes doesn't appear. It could be `Birthday` or a few other options. Order of the `<b>Label:</b>`  isn't guaranteed and data is very unstructured, hence the difficulty.

Comment: Grab the first `<a>` element which comes after the `<b>` element whose text contains `Location`. And then all of that elements `<a>` siblings until you hit a `<br>`

Comment: I'm unsure of how to grab the next sibling regardless of what element it is or ideally, how to grab a list of elements between 2 elements.

Comment: Well, if nothing at all can be relied upon, your problem cannot be solved. Can you at least guarantee that all relevant `a` elements will be followed by a `br` element? Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Yes. All `a` elements have a trailing `br`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath expression:

```
//b[contains(.,'Location')]/following-sibling::a[not(preceding-sibling::b[contains(.,'Ethnicity')])]/text()
```

translates to

```
//b[contains(.,'Location')]       Select `b` elements anywhere in the document and only
                                  if their text content contains "Location"
/following-sibling::a             Of those `b` elements select following sibling
                                  elements `a` 
[not(preceding-sibling::b         but only if they (i.e. the `a` elements) are not
                                  preceded by a `b` element
[contains(.,'Ethnicity')])]       whose text nodes contain "Ethnicity"
/text()                           return all text nodes of those `a` elements
```

and yields (individual results separated by `-------`)

```
London
-----------------------
UK
-----------------------
Baltimore
-----------------------
Maryland
-----------------------
United States
```

It relies on the fact that the `a` elements you are looking for are *between* the `b` element that contains `Location` and the `b` element that contains `Ethnicity`. Is this always the case?

---

**EDIT**: As a response to your edit, try the following similar expression:

```
//b[contains(.,'Location')]/following-sibling::a[not(preceding-sibling::b[preceding-sibling::b[contains(.,'Location')]])]/text()
```

Comment: Thank you. You're edit is very flexible and is extracting everything correctly.

Comment: @Ash You are welcome. If you need additional info about this expression, I'm glad to add more details.